# Error al importar librerias de python

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Chicos necesito ayuda, descargué unas librerías satisfactoriamente y las importé a sublime text 3, y cuando compilo me aparece que no las encuentra.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import mysql.connector
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
import random
import time
```

A la hora de compilar me sale lo siguiente,

```
    import pyttsx3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

Si borro el import pyttsx3, me sale el mismo error pero con import speech_recognition., necesito de su colaboración, uso Sublime Text.

Comment: En caso que estés trabajando con entornos virtuales, recuerda activar el entorno en el que tienes instaladas las librerías antes de compilar o ejecutar el programa. Si quieres saber si tu venv tiene instaladas las librerías prueba a utilizar pip freeze cuando el entorno esté activado, y se te mostrará el conjunto de librerías instaladas.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder resolver este error tienes que ir en el **[símbolo de sistema(cmd)](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/windows-10-c%C3%B3mo-ejecuto-el-s%C3%ADmbolo-del/bbf8b8cb-c9ed-42bd-8e06-096d99721e86)**. Despues de esto tienes que escribir los siguientes comandos en este orden

```
py -m pip install -u pyttsx3
```

Si esto no funciona intenta hacer lo siguiente:

Primero **eliminar** pyttsx3

```
py -m pip uninstall pyttsx3
```

Despues **instala pipenv**

```
py -m pip install -u pipenv
```

Por ultimo **reinstala pyttsx3**

```
py -m pip install -u pyttsx3
```

Si esto no funciona te dejo la pagina de [Pyttsx3](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/)

Espero haberte ayudado, si puedes aceptar la pregunta en el cheque me ayudarías mucho, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que instalar esa librería, desde el **cmd** o tu **shell**, pone:

```sh
pip install pyttsx3
```